# BigQuery Scheduled Query using MERGE statement

Tags: google-bigquery, dml

We have a number of Scheduled Queries in BigQuery that uses the DML keyword `MERGE INTO [destination table]`. These used to run OK before, but until recently the execution began to fail with error:

```
Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements
```

It turns out, it now requires a destination table, even though there is one in the MERGE statement itself.

[image: Scheduled Query requires destination table]

How can this be fixed or what's the correct configuration so it would run as it used to? What's the complication if I add the same destination table while the same table name being in the MERGE statement already ?

Comment: I had a similar issue recently while creating a BQML model. I could only create the model after unchecking the "Use cached results". If this tip can help...

Answer (score 0):

[Uncheck the destination table for query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbhlp.png)

If you're using DML Merge query for set up scheduler, you must disable destination table, because you've already set the source and the target table inside the Merge. Hope this help